# Centering of content below cmidrule

Tags: rules, booktabs

I'm trying to figure out how I can center the columns below a multicolumn statement with a very long text because my current result does not look fine.

I didn't find anything related but it is also very hard to describe by a term so maybe I just did not have the right term.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}

\ra{1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{>{\kern-\tabcolsep}lll<{\kern-\tabcolsep}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{l}{Long Text  .....}\\
\cmidrule{1-3}
A & B & C \\
\midrule
\endhead
A & B & C \\
A & B & C \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: How exactly do you want it to look?

Comment: The A, B and C should be centered below the long text and not somehow left aligned as there

Comment: The negative `\kern` is shifting the columns left. If you want that, then I don't see how they can be centred.

Comment: Actually, I also had the problem before with the `@{}` instead of the kerns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this? Note that the kerns won't make any difference here, because they are not implemented for the longest row which obviously determines the total width.

[image: Centred]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable,array,calc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
\ra{1.3}
\begin{document}
  \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\shorttextlength}}
\newlength\longtextlength
\newlength\shorttextlength
\settowidth\longtextlength{Long Text \dots.}
\addtolength\longtextlength{-4\tabcolsep}
\setlength\shorttextlength{\longtextlength/3}
\begin{longtable}{CCC}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{3}{l}{Long Text \dots.}\\
  \cmidrule{1-3}
  A & B & C \\
  \midrule
  \endhead
  A & B & C \\
  A & B & C \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```